# Refresh a <div> created by an html.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

In my Rails app, I have a portion of a page created by an html.erb file:

```
<div id="progressbars">
    <% @all_active_threads.each do | active_thread | %>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="progressdiv<%= active_thread.thread_id %>" class="progress progress-striped active span6">
                <div id="progressbar<%= active_thread.thread_id %>" class="bar" style="width: <%= active_thread.progress %>%;"><%= active_thread.campaign %></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

This quickly and elegantly creates a series of progress bars for each active thread object in my app every time I reload my page. I've set up my javascript code to update these progress bars' values, but what I'd like to accomplish is to have the parent 'progressbars' div refresh itself whenever a thread is created or destroyed, thereby creating an up-to-date list of progress bars for the number of threads that exist.

I know I can manually add and remove divs with Javascript, but is there an easier way to just refresh the div in question so that it'll run through its loop and create the needed progress bars?

Thank you!

Comment: The erb template only renders when you load the page or manually call render on the template.  You can potentially make an ajax call that returns this view and insert it into the DOM. To answer your question you cannot make it refresh itself magically. You could however use a JS library that watches the state of the thread and removes it when necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I really like the sound of your last suggestion. Are there any general-use libraries you're aware of that will allow me to do that? Also, if I created a partial and added it to the main .html.erb, could I call render on just the partial?

Comment: I use Backbone.js and it works pretty well, Angular.js is getting big at the moment as well. All rendering is considered finished when the page is loaded and presented to the user, unless you later make a call to a controller that calls a render method.The main .html.erb file is just the layout file and is really no different than the partial. If you go the Backbone or Angular route you can use their templating language and render the template in JS, which I also recommend doing.  It can then handle itself all the way through.

Comment: Yes, I'm using AngularJS for other aspects of the app, such as widgets like the progress bar and date pickers, but honestly I'm very new to AngularJS. Is there a tutorial available somewhere you can recommend to get me started?

Comment: Im not very familiar with Angular, but maybe checkout [this](http://stephanebegaudeau.tumblr.com/post/48776908163/everything-you-need-to-understand-to-start-with)